# Issue with css transitions

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

So I'm creating a drop-down menu so when the user hovers over a section's title or content a div will change in size from 0px to 370px to display that section's content. Everything runs smoothly when the user slowly (or with adequate speed) scrolls over each section; however, when the user scrolls too quickly the animations get buggy. I'm assuming it's because of the css transitions--more specifically their timings. Is there anyway to have smoother transitions?

**BONUS:** Can someone tell me how to change the background-color of the titles when that certain section is being viewed by the user? I want to do this without adding anymore id's or classes.

**FYI:** This is a complete redesign because initially I had too much DRY code with javascript, so now I'm re-doing this drop-down menu with as little javascript as possible.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>list</title>
    <!--links in font-->
    <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Yanone+Kaffeesatz:400,200' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
    <!--links in jQuery-->
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<style type="text/css">
/* do not  include in production */
    * {
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        border: 0;
    }
    body {
        background-color: whitesmoke;
        font-family: 'Yanone Kaffeesatz', sans-serif;
        color: white;
    }
    .cards {
        background: white;
        padding: 10px;
        margin: 5px auto;
        border: #DDD solid 1px;
        box-shadow: 1px 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
    }
/* INCLUDE */
    #n-wrap {
        width: 950px;
        height: 600px;
        background-color: whitesmoke;
        overflow: hidden;
    }
    .n-titles {
        line-height: 50px;
        width: 950px;
        height: 50px;
        background-color: #888;
        transition: background-color 0.5s ease;
    }
    .n-titles:nth-child(n+2):hover {
        background-color: rgb(96, 223, 229);
        cursor: pointer;
    }
    .n-titles:nth-child(n+2):hover + .n-items {
        height: 370px;
    }
    .n-items {
        height: 0px;
        width: 100%;
        transition: height 0.5s ease;
        background-color: white;
    }
    .n-items:hover {
        height: 370px;
    }
    #open {
        height: 370px;
    }
</style>
<body>
    <center>
        <div id="n-wrap" class="cards">
            <div class="n-titles">FEATURED</div>
            <div class="n-titles">Most Popular</div>
            <div class="n-items pseudo-open" id="open"></div>
            <div class="n-titles">On Sale</div>
            <div class="n-items"></div>
            <div class="n-titles">Newest</div>
            <div class="n-items"></div>
        </div>  
    </center>   
</body>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {
            //always has the first section displayed when the drop-down is not being hovered
            $(".n-items, .n-titles:not(.n-titles:first-child)").hover(function() {
                $("#open").removeAttr("id");
            });
            $(".n-items, .n-titles").mouseout(function() {
                $(".pseudo-open").attr("id", "open");
            })  
        });
    </script>
</html>
```

Comment: the transitions seems smooth on my chrome 49. ps: `<center>` is not supported by html5, use css instead.

Comment: You'll probably need to make the animations wait somehow; e.g. if one is playing, don't play another one until at least enough time has passed for the animation to play out completely. Or do it on click rather than hover.